# React {$$typeof: Symbol(react.element) , How to check if the component return null or html

Tags: reactjs

There are multiple files which return either html component or null
if i log all the component it log same thing

$$typeof: Symbol
key: null
props: Object
ref: null
type: ƒ Test()
_owner: FiberNode
_store: Object
: Object

How can i know if it has retuned value

EG file : https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-vhhhyz?file=App.tsx